# Android fragments in AppCompatActivity class

Tags: android, fragment, appcompatactivity

I would like to ask you about AppCompatActivity (generated by Android studio) and custom fragments. I've made an AppCompatActivity with the built-in generator in Android studio. But i want to use my custom classes so i've made 3 layout xml's and 3 classes. E.g:

```
public class ThermoMeter extends Fragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1thermometer, container, false);
return rootView;
```

In my main activity i use them as the following:

```
 public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                ThermoMeter tabThermoMeter = new ThermoMeter();
                return tabThermoMeter;
            case 1:
                RealTimeThermoChart rtThermoChart = new RealTimeThermoChart();
                return rtThermoChart;
            case 2:
                HistoryChart historyChart = new HistoryChart();
                return historyChart;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

I would like to ask you that how can i add my custom classes (which are extends from Fragment) to R.id or i dont know where to use: `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);`
? I need to know which is the current active fragments in my activity class and i have to update the textviews in the active fragment with new data from the activity class. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

At your Activity

```
   public void ThermoMeter (){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment_ThermoMeter fThermoMeter = new Fragment_ThermoMeter();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fThermoMeter, "ThermoMeter");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

same thing for each fragment.. thank call the method you want :)

at your xml layout_activity

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bg1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it!
Where shall i call Thermometer() in my activity? Instead of the generated get method?

Comment: yes you should call on create in your activity, than Fragment called ThermoMeter will be shown